# How to use kafka client in order to consume from topic using java language

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to consume messages from topic that I know that produces messages (kafka producer is already exist by design, all I have to do is to write a code that consume the messages).

this is my code:

```
public class ConsumerManager extends ShutdownableThread {

    //    private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;
//    static String brokers = Configuration.prop.getProperty("suite.pusher.defaultParams.kafkaBrokers");
    static String brokers = "<kafka_server_ip>:9092";
    static private Producer<String, String> m_kafkaProducers;
    static private int m_CurrentProducerIndex;
    static private int maxKafkaMessageSizeInMb = 8;
    static private String kafkaCompressionCodec = "lz4";
    static private String maxKafkaAcks = "1";
    static private int maxKafkaRetries;
    static private int kafkaBatchSize = 16384;
    static private int kafkaBufferMemory = 33554432;
    static private int kafkaConnectionsMaxIdleMs = 540000;
    static private int kafkaLingerMs = 0;
    static private int kafkaMaxBlocks = 100;
    static private int kafkaMaxRequestSize = 1048576;
    static private int kafkaRequestTimeoutMs = 300000;
    static private int kafkaMaxInFlightRequestsPerConnection = 5;
    static private int kafkaBatchNumMessages = 10000;
    static private int kafkeQueueBufferingMaxMs = 10;
    static private int kafkaFetchWaitMaxMs = 10;
    static private int kafkaSocketBlockingMaxMs = 10;
    static private boolean kafkaSocketNagleDisable = false;
    String kafkaPrefix = Configuration.prop.getProperty("suite.pusher.defaultParams.kafkaTopicPrefix");

    private final Boolean isAsync = false;
    static String TOPIC = "proc_422_26952";//"proc_69686_61";//" "qa_69313_2";
    private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
    private final String topics;

    public ConsumerManager(String topic) {
        super("KafkaConsumerExample", false);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "CageConsumerGroup");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        this.topics = topic;

    }
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topics));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.key() + ", " + record.value() + ") at offset " + record.offset());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInterruptible() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

however when I get to the line: `ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10000);` nothing happen and the test is finished and I am unable to see the records or to know that the topic got the messages and I can then display them to the console.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server host:9092 --topic proc_422_26952 --from-beginning` ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous - I used this command: 
`sudo ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic proc_422_26952 --from-beginning`

and I saw all the data that was streamed to this topic... 

it looks like this:
"suggested term\",\"data-stsearchterm\":\"\",\"href\":\"http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ryobi-16-in-40-Volt-Lithium-Ion-Cordless-Walk-Behind-Battery-Push-Mower-Battery-and-Charger-Not-Included-RY40104A/203362215\"},\"i\":\"a356\"},\"t\":false,\"pn\":\"li214\"},{\"n\":{\"nt\":1,\"tn\":\"DIV\",\"a\":

Comment: Try to use a different group id and make sure that your offset starts at the earliest. Plus, polling for 10 seconds will be a blocking call... The console consumer does 100ms polls

Comment: No matter what I tried I cannot consume records into my topics using code, manually I can do it easily.

Comment: Please attach the log4j output from your client. To enable log4j, set the following jvm argument: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/parth/to/log4j.properties`. If you don't already have a properties file, you can grab it from Kafka: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties

Comment: Please add that into your question and not in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I changed all my consumer class from scratch and now it seems to work , this is my code:

```
public class ConsumerManager  {

    static String brokers = "<kafka_host>:9092";
    private ExecutorService executor;
    String kafkaPrefix = "proc_422_26952";
    private final Boolean isAsync = false;
    static String TOPIC; //"proc_69686_61";//" "qa_69313_2";

    public ConsumerManager(String topicName) {

        TOPIC = topicName;
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
        props.put("group.id", "CageConsumerGroupIO");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "500");
        props.put("key.deserializer",
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer",
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(TOPIC));
        System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + TOPIC);
        int i = 0;

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n",
                        record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                System.out.println(record.value());
            }


        }
    }
```